# drupal_map_assoc($array)

Tags: drupal

```
     function _ahah_example_get_first_dropdown_options() {

     $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECt  code,descr1 FROM dbtest.regions");
     oci_execute($stid);
     $region= array();
     while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))) {
     $region[$row['CODE']]= $row['DESCR1'];
                                }
  $region['']='Select';
  oci_free_statement($stid);
       oci_close($conn);

      return drupal_map_assoc($region);
       }
```

but it returns the key and the value equal I need the original key to be returne cause im using it's value in a javascript function?anyone would know how to return the original Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you should be able to skip `drupal_map_assoc` and just return `$region`. Give that a try and see if you like the results.

Reference http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_map_assoc/6

Comment: I've tried the $region it doesn't work cz im using 3 dependent drop down list.this is just the first one

Comment: region with out drupal_map_assoc should work..please cleare the cache if you found any problem